# How to stream audio from microphone to speaker?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, microphone

I'm looking to stream audio directly from the microphone to the default audio output medium, whether it be the speaker or the 3.5mm jack.

The mechanisms I've found for playing audio appears to hinge on providing a static amount of bytes to play in a SoundEffect, like so:

```
SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(stream.ToArray(), microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
soundIsPlaying = true;
soundInstance.Play();
```

I could continually play SoundEffects of 500 ms or less to achieve my goal, but I was wondering if there was a more sophisticated way which involved the microphone continually writing to a MemoryStream, which an audio playback control can continually read.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If you use the main speaker and microphone the feedback will probably make this sound pretty bad. Think of a really bad speakerphone with delay and whistling... Is this the effect you're after?

Comment: I'm specifically targeting the 3.5mm jack, but I wasn't sure how bad the feedback would be, so I left the speaker in my question. You are correct though, I don't want that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went about solving this problem by extending the MediaStreamSource class with a class that used the microphone to provide samples to the MediaElement Player.

If there's any demand for this block of code I will happily post it somewhere. For now, here's a code snippet to help you out if you're trying to do the same thing:

```
// Provides audio samples from AudioSampleProvider property.
//  (MediaStreamType parameter will always equal Audio.)
protected override void GetSampleAsync(MediaStreamType mediaStreamType)
{
    // start the microphone capture if it's not started yet
    if (microphone.State == MicrophoneState.Stopped)
    {
        microphone.Start();
    }
}

// gets called back when the microphone's buffer is ready
private void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve audio data
    microphone.GetData(buffer);

    // Reset MemoryStream object
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Write the newly acquired data into the memory stream
    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // Send out the sample
    ReportGetSampleCompleted(new MediaStreamSample(mediaStreamDescription,
                                                    memoryStream,
                                                    0,
                                                    buffer.Length,
                                                    0, 
                                                    mediaSampleAttributes));
}
```

You basically just report that a sample is ready whenever the microphone buffer is returned. This results in smooth playback.

Comment: I'll play with this later to make sure I can follow, but I wanted to say that I would most likely want to see your code sample. I'm looking at taking this a touch further and I'll likely need all the help I can get. Your extended MediaStreamSource may be exactly what I need to get started.

Comment: Sure thing, I uploaded the entire project for you at: http://sdrv.ms/16vz7Jb  It's a Megaphone app that just echoes out whatever it hears in the speaker. But be warned, there's no acoustic echo cancellation so it'll echo like mad if the microphone can pick up the speaker's output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. I'll play with it later to see how close it is to what I'm going for. I was hoping to merge microphone input with music playback so that if I'm listening to headphones while driving (the only sound system I have :/), I can pick up more background noise. I somehow doubt the mic works like normal windows where you can just preview the mic input and get the same effect because it's not like I need to *record* the mic. I think you'll be getting me very close and for that I thank you.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck on your endeavors, let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

Nico

When trying your MegaPhone project, I hit the following error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". 
Can you have a look? Thanks

at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MediaStreamSource_OnGetSampleCompleted(MediaElement mediaElement, Int32 streamIndex, StreamInteropWrapper streamWrapper, InternalStreamWrapper internalStream, Int64 offset, Int64 count, Int64 timeInHundredNanoseconds, Int64 durationInHundredNanoseconds, Int32 attributeCount, Int32[] attributeLengths, StringBuilder attributes)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement.MediaSourceReportGetSampleCompleted(MediaStreamSample mediaStreamSample)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaStreamSource.ReportGetSampleCompleted(MediaStreamSample mediaStreamSample)
   at Megaphone.MicrophoneSource.microphone_BufferReady(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone.OnBufferReady(EventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.MicrophoneCollection.OnBufferReady(UInt32 handle)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update()
   at Megaphone.MainPage.dt_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)