# How to redirect audio stream from microphone to headphone instantly

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, microphone

I need to open the incoming  audio stream from the microphone and address it  instantly to the headphones so you  hear what is being acquired by the microphone.

it is not possible to do this using xna microphone, because it is  necessary to pass through a buffer that slows down the headphone listening. I think needs to use Windows.Phone.Media.Capture as AudioDevice and perhaps AudioSink but do not understand how. Do you have any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stream audio from microphone to speaker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405771/how-to-stream-audio-from-microphone-to-speaker)

Comment: no, I need to address instantly to the headphone, without latency

Comment: No latency is not possible - the electrons have to travel between the microphone to the speaker at least, not to mention the OS' software layers involved.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts Many audio codecs have are able to loop microphone/headset back to the output mixer with only the converters' latency.  
This is not to say that this functionality is exposed in an API.

Comment: @Marko I agree - but if such an API was available on this platform (which it is not) that would/should already be in the linked question.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts the latency is mainly due to the filling of the buffer used in the xna framework, whose minimum size can not be less than 100ms. The electrons are fast enough for what I plan to do. If you open the microphone channel on the audio mixer of an windows 95 does not notice a valuable latency

Answer (score 0):

It looks you've got tighter latency requirements than the a previous question in this area. For phone 8 the best latency result is probably going to be to use the DirectX audio APIs from C++.

The documentation [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj715884%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) will tell you which APIs you can use from the phone, but if I know MSDN I expect you will need to go digging to find examples of how to use them - and when you find them you'll need to be familiar with C/C++, and how to set up a "hybrid" C#/C++ project in Visual Studio.

Even then you'll have to try and it out on a real phone to see if the latency performance is good enough for your purposes.